# how do i make it so a word has value in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, numbers

I would like for google sheets to recognise a word as a number such as when I do =(SUM)A2+B2 and A2 is the word 'dingus' for it to think it is 100. It must be in a way where I can just put 'dingus' in a cell and use that in a math problem, for google sheets to just assume it means 100. Ie, I just write dingus in a cell, with another cell refering to it in a math problem, and haveing dingus be a valid number with a value of 100, by default.

Comment: [Creating a named function](https://i.imgur.com/SXxsYe9.png) should simplify this further just in case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VLOOKUP. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Phq_kklFXvh-a46SRZUAxb7EUVHBXsaVkw-vJTtug2Q/edit?usp=sharing) is a spreadsheet with a lookup table (columns E and F) assigning a value to each word. Using VLOOKUP (column C), you can add the words by referencing the lookup table.